# VLANs still exist on my switch as I reset it

Tags: vlan, cisco-commands

I reset my Cisco 3750 by `write erase` and then del the vlan.dat file from the flash and reload it... but `sh VTP status` is still showing the VLAN... 
why are the VLANs still there after I deleted the database. What is the proper process to delete the VLANs?

Comment: Deleting the vlan database (vlan.dat) from flash is the only way i know of. Could you post the output of what you are doing?

Comment: You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. For example: output from commands like `show vtp status` and `show vlan`, a network topology (i.e. is your 3750 a single device or connected to other network devices), etc.

Comment: Well, VTP will reload the VLANs from another switch acting as a VTP server (the default). You can set the VTP mode as `transparent` to disable VTP.